# referenciar class css en PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, css

¿Cómo puedo referenciar el siguiente .class que está en una etiqueta de HTML dentro de PHP? De la siguiente manera no me la reconoce

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "<h2><center>CURSOS</center></h2>
<table class='tablaCursos'>
<thead>
                           <tr>
                                          <th>CÓDIGO CURSO</th>
                                          <th>NOMBRE</th>
                                          <th>HORARIO</th>
                                          <th>FECHA INICIO</th>
                                          <th>FECHA DE FIN</th>
                                          <th>MONITOR</th>
                                          <th>PRECIO</th>
                                          <th>SOCIOS</th>
                                          <th>ACCIONES</th>
                           </tr>
                           </thead>";
```

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que estas tratando de hacer.

Comment: es una parte de un código de una web de consulta de socios y cursos, necesito referenciar esa tabla html que esta dentro del codigo en php para darla estilo con css

Comment: Como la estas referenciando?

Comment: vale ya lo tengo, en vez de hacer un .class para la tabla he hecho un .class para un fieldset que recoja toda la tabla y ya la he dado el estilo. Gracias.

Comment: Así como está la clase de la tabla está bien, lo que te faltaría es incluir la cascada en ese archivo php